# How to sync database with remote database with Dexie

Tags: laravel, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, quasar-framework, dexie

I making Notes PWA App that work offline and online.

I am saving notes records on IndexedDB with [Dexie.js](https://dexie.org/). I am using [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) as frontend and backend as [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/).

I want to sync IndexedDB Database with remote database. How can I do?

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?

Comment: @RitobrotoMukherjee Yes

Comment: please share the solution in a comment, if possible

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at Dexie Cloud - David has worked this out for Postgres.
2. If you want to write your own, it is a LOT MORE WORK than you think.
   We wrote our own to work with SQL Server and C#
   (it is proprietary, I can't share it)
   Months later, we are still finding edge cases - there are many edge cases.
3. If you still want to write your own, you are probably mistaken..
4. If records can be created client side - use GUID identifiers
5. If it is an existing database with integer identifiers, add a GUID identifier field.
6. Set aside a few months of time to work out the rest.